# Minimal completion of a Boolean algebra

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, universal-algebra

According to Halmos (Lectures on Boolean Algebras, p. 92), the completion of Boolean algebra $A$ is a complete Boolean algebra $B$ together with a monomorphism $h$ from $A$ into $B$ such that

(1) $h$ preserves all suprema.

(2) The complete Boolean algebra generated by $h(A)$ in $B$ is $B$ itself.

Moreover, a completion $(B,h)$ is minimal if, corresponding to every completion $(C,k)$, there exists a complete monomorphism $f$ from $B$ into $C$ such that $f\circ h=k$

Question 1: If $h(A)$ generates B, then, by definition, B is the smallest complete Boolean algebra containing $h(A)$. Why is this fact not a sufficient condition to define minimality?

Question 2: Is there another way to define minimality (than the one provided above)?

Answer (score 2):

You should cite Halmos properly. Halmos does not define **the** completion of a Boolean algebra", but **a** completion of a Boolean algebra. Then he defines *a minimal completion* using a universal property and insists that

> It is not obvious that there are any completions at all, let alone minimal ones.

**Question 1**. The fact that the complete Boolean algebra generated by $h(A)$ in $B$ is $B$ itself does not suffice to insure that $B$ satisfies the universal property.

**Question 2**. You could use Halmos' Theorem 11 from the same book as a definition, but it is not really simpler. In this case, you would define the completion of a Boolean algebra $A$ as the Boolean algebra of regular open sets of the Stone dual of $A$. But you could also use another result, known as the Glivenko–Stone theorem:

> The minimal completion of a Boolean algebra is also its [Dedekind-MacNeille
>    completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind%E2%80%93MacNeille_completion).

Comment: Re Question 1: The fact that $h(A)$ generates $B$ as a complete Boolean algebra does not on its own guarantee the universal property, but together with property (1) it does.  See my answer.

Comment: I think the OP is not questioning whether or not the complete BA generated by $h(A)$ suffices to satisfy the universal property, but rather the universal property itself given that the BA generated by $h(A)$ is already the smallest in some sense. For me, the universal property is some form of guarantee of unicity (up to isomorphism).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, properties (1) and (2) are sufficient to define a minimal completion (that is, by Halmos's definition, every completion is minimal).  Indeed, let $(B,h)$ be a minimal completion of $A$ and let $(C,k)$ be any other completion.  By the universal property of $(B,h)$, there exists a complete monomorphism $f:B\to C$ such that $fh=k$.  The image of $f$ is then a complete subalgebra of $C$, which contains $f(h(A))=k(A)$.  But by property (2) of $(C,k)$, this implies the image of $f$ is all of $C$.  Thus $f$ is surjective, and hence an isomorphism.  Since $(B,h)$ is minimal, this implies $(C,k)$ is minimal as well.

[Note that this argument depends crucially on the existence of at least one minimal completion.  So Halmos's notion of minimality is not useless--it is still useful as a step along the way to prove that a completion (in the sense of (1) and (2)) is unique up to isomorphism.  Still, Halmos seems to have been unaware of this redundancy when he wrote the book.]

Comment: Well, Halmos suggests a counterexample as an exercise. I did not check the validity of the exercise, but here it is. Let $A$ be the Boolean algebra generated by the intervals of the form $[a,b[$ in $[0,1]$. Halmos mentions that Borel modulo measure 0 and Borel modulo meager are both (non isomorphic) completions of $A$.

Comment: The modulo measure 0 version does not satisfy (1) (for instance, if you take a collection of half-open intervals whose union is the complement of a fat Cantor set, its supremum in $A$ is $1$, while its supremum in Borel modulo measure 0 is not).  Halmos seems to be aware of this, in that he says these algebras are "in a natural sense completions" rather than outright saying they really are completions in the sense of the earlier definition.

Comment: Very nice. I missed Halmos' "in a natural sense"...

Comment: So, to summarise, (1) and (2) are sufficient to define a minimal completion because the complete Boolean algebra generated by $h(A)$ is $B$; in other words, $B$ is the smallest complete BA containing $h(A)$. The universal property guarantees moreover the unicity of the completion in the sense that any two minimal completions are isomorphic Is this correct?

Comment: @student: When I say (1) and (2) are sufficient to define a minimal completion, _all_ I'm saying is that (1) and (2) imply Halmos's definition of "minimal completion".  I'm not saying anything about the appropriateness of the term "minimal"; it's just a word.  I really don't recommend your phrasing "$B$ is the smallest complete BA containing $h(A)$"; rather, $B$ is the smallest complete _subalgebra of $B$_ containing $h(A)$.  There are lots of other complete algebras containing a copy of $A$, which a priori might be "smaller" or "larger" in some sense.

Comment: However, as it turns out, for any complete algebra containing a copy of $A$ and satisfying (1), the complete subalgebra generated by the copy of $A$ is isomorphic to $B$.  So it is reasonable to call $B$ the smallest complete BA containing a copy of $A$, but _only_ because of this uniqueness up to isomorphism.