# Example of a completion of a Boolean Algebra that is not minimal

Tags: boolean-algebra

Let $A$ be a Boolean Algebra. The pair, $(B, \rho:A \to B)$, is a completion of $A$ if $\rho$ is an injective homomorphism, preserves arbitrary meets and joins, and the complete Boolean Algebra generated by $\rho(A)$ is all of $B$.

We call a completion $(B, \rho)$ minimal if all other completions $(C, \tau)$ factor uniquely through $\rho$ (i.e. there exists a unique homomorphism $\sigma:C \to B$ such that $\sigma\circ \tau = \rho$).

My problem is this: it is not entirely obvious to me that any completion will look different from a minimal completion of $A$. What I mean is this: if $\rho(A)$ and $\tau(A)$ sit inside $B$ and $C$ respectively, then it is not clear to me that the subalgebra generated by those two sets will not be isomorphic already.

Can anyone provide me with a concrete example of a Boolean Algebra $A$, a minimal completion $B$, and a completion $C$ that is **not** isomorphic to $B$?

Comment: There is none (and so this definition is pretty silly, though it does appear in one well-known book).  I believe I've answered a question on this before...

Comment: Although, you seem to have not quite written the definition correctly: the homomorphism $\sigma$ must be required to be complete.

Comment: OK, I've found the old question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2598587/86856.  There the definition is actually slightly different in that $\sigma$ is moreover required to be injective.  So a more complicated argument is needed than my argument there if we're using your definition (assuming you require $\sigma$ to be complete but not necessarily injective).